# Inserting a dictionary to a sorted list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary, insert

I've been trying to insert a new dictionary to a sorted list of dictionaries while maintaining the order.
To sort the list of dictionaries I've used `sample_dict = sorted(sample_dict, key=lambda k: k['ID'])`
It seems the only solution would be to iterate over the list and compare the ID of each entry with the previous one but this solution does not sound optimal (time-wise).
I have also found [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) library which allows entry insertion in lists while keeping the correct order but it seems it does not work with dictionaries ( throws `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict'` ). I also want to mention that my entries contains a lot key-values pairs (21) and I am not sure if there are any alternatives to dictionaries (e.g tuples). Lastly, I want to mention that "ID" is a string.
Is there something I am missing or is iterating over the whole list for each insertion the only solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried with bisect?

Comment: I've tried bisect's insort,insort_left. Here is a minimal example
bisect.insort(sample_dict, {'id': 6, 'name': 'Jenkins'})

Comment: Have you tried [Sorted Dict](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sorteddict.html) from [SortedContainers](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/index.html)?

Comment: I have not. I will try it and get back with the results. Thanks a lot for the help, I really do appreciate it

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately `bisect` doesn't allow you to give a `key` parameter like `sorted` does.  But it's easy to get around it by keeping a list of tuples instead of dictionaries.  Less-than on a tuple compares element by element, so if the first element of the tuple is your key then everything works.

```
sample_dict = sorted(((k['ID'], k) for k in sample_dict))
```

As mentioned in the comments, this still fails if two list items have the same ID because the comparison moves on to the second tuple element.  The solution is to add another tuple element that is guaranteed to never be equal.

```
sample_dict = sorted(((k['ID'], index, k) for index,k in enumerate(sample_dict)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!
After trying your line of code I receive:
SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized.
After adding the parenthesis
sample_dict = sorted((k['ID'], k for k in sample_dict))
it throws "Invalid Syntax"

Comment: @Gerasimos is `sample_dict` starting out as a list of dictionaries?  The code presented in your question made it appear so, but it's not 100% clear.

Comment: @Gerasimos and thanks for pointing out my error in the generator expression, I've fixed that part of the answer.

Comment: Yes, sample_dict is a list of dictionaries which is sorted using the line of code shown above. The generator expression still yields an invalid syntax error pointing at for, would that suggest an incompatibility with python version (3.7.9)? I am sorry about these questions but I am new to Python and especially to generators and list comprehension.

Comment: @Gerasimos I have to apologize for pushing out an untested answer.  Usually parentheses are optional when creating a tuple, but in this case they are not.  I'm updating the answer, and this time I've tried it myself and it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark. I will try it out and get back with the results.

Comment: As a follow up, I could not make it work ( received again the same error: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict') so I ended up doing a binary search (pretty much what bisect does on a custom way) and it worked perfectly. Again, thanks a lot for your time

Comment: @Gerasimos that would happen if you had two list items with the same ID, the comparison will move on to the second member of the tuple.  I should have anticipated that, sorry.